# Express not setting a cookie

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am using React as frontend and express as backend. I have a problem with setting a cookie in browser.

frontend:

```
axios.defaults.withcredentials = true
```

backend:

The code I use in `/signup` route

```
res.cookie('token',token,{
httpOnly:true,
sameSite:'none',
secure:true,
});
res.status(201).json("status":"Success","message":"authenticated")
```

Cors

```
app.use(cors({
credentials:true,
origin:['http://localhost:3000']
}))
```

The response header contains the
`Set-Cookie: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiNjE3MmIyZmU4MTgzMWM2ZGJhOWRhNzU0IiwiaWF0IjoxNjM0OTE...`

but it not saved in Application > Cookies

Can anyone help? Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Your cookie probably counts as a third-party cookie (search for that term on Stack Overflow). Your browser's DevTools > Network > Cookies may also offer more information.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen does secure attribute works in localhost?

Comment: Secure only works over https, but also over http://localhost:xxxx.